# Is there any way I can do pattern matching of a string that start with numbers between 0 and 9 followed by characters?

Tags: sql

I want to extract patterns that start with numbers between 0 and 9 followed by a code.

For e.g :

I want to find the pattern '3SN' in the string 'RMK A02 GRE53SNB32'.

I was trying out the query :
LIKE '%[0-9]SN%'

But it is not working.

Can someone please help me out!

Comment: You'll most likely need regular expressions and MySQL's [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) operator.

Comment: the answer to your question is `yes` ... please don't ask a question that has a yes/no answer

Comment: @jsotola  A "Can I do x?" can easily be inferred as "How do I do x?". All it takes is a bit of empathy.

Comment: @Evert how do you know that the actual question is not `why does my solution not work?` ... there is no reason why anyone should have to guess what the OP wants to know

Comment: What database? Of the major databases only SQL Server supports the [0-9] part of your LIKE.

Comment: @Brian I wanted to run it in Teradata. It is working perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `regexp_substr()`

```
select regexp_substr(col, '[0-9]SN')
```

Or a regular expression.  In MySQL, this would be:

```
where col regexp '[0-9]SN'
```

In Teradata:

```
where regexp_instr(col, '[0-9]SN') > 0
```

Comment: Knew this guy would answer straight up :D

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, but it Throws an error stating : 
[3707]Syntax error, expected something like a 'SUCCEEDS' ,  'MEETS' , 'PRECEDES', 'IN' keyword .

Comment: @AnubhavNehru . . . Do you have the `select` and `from` clauses in your query?

Comment: @AnubhavNehru `regexp_instr` returns the position where the RegEx is found, add `>0`

Comment: Thanks everyone I was able to run this. Thanks for saving my day guys! @GordonLinoff